# Autofac exception in nopCommerce project (Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.NoConstructorsFoundException: 'No accessible constructors were found )

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, autofac, nopcommerce

I am trying to add a new page in the public store of nopCommerce. For that I have create Entity, model, factory, controller, Interface and service etc.

But as soon as I am running my nopCommerce project, it shows me following error.

> **`Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.NoConstructorsFoundException: 'No accessible constructors were found for the type 'Nop.Web.Factories.SupportRequestModelFactory'.'`**

I'm using nopCommerce version 4.50 version.

What are the causing of this error and how can it be resolved?

[Here is a picture about that error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBpJq.png)

I tried to find the error in Controller and factory, but couldn't find the exact solution for this!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I don't know much about NopCommerce but it looks like AutoFac is unable to create an instance of `SupportRequestModelFactory`. I assume this is a class you created and probably are registering it somewhere with AutoFac so make sure your registration is properly defined and a constructor matching such registration exists.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot? On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A **[mcve]** showing enough code for others here to reproduce your problem would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: However, *No accessible constructors were found for the type `Nop.Web.Factories.SupportRequestModelFactory`* seems self-explanatory. You need to make the relevant constructor public, as explained in [this post](https://www.nopcommerce.com/en/boards/topic/95763/error-no-accessible-constructors-were-found#302085) by ANISHA RAMANUJ over at https://www.nopcommerce.com/. If this doesn't fix the problem, please include a (possibly simplified) version of `SupportRequestModelFactory` in your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. -[From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/33457740)

Answer (score 1):

`NoConstructorsFoundException` happens when you don't have a public constructor for a class. To resolve this issue make sure you have a public constructor in your SupportRequestModelFactory class and pass all the necessary services in the parameter of the public constructor.

Here is an Example:

```
    public partial class SupportRequestModelFactory : ISupportRequestModelFactory
    {
        private readonly ILocalizationService _localizationService;
        private readonly ILocalizedModelFactory _localizedModelFactory;

        public SupportRequestModelFactory(
            ILocalizationService localizationService,
            ILocalizedModelFactory localizedModelFactory)
        {
            _localizationService = localizationService;
            _localizedModelFactory = localizedModelFactory;
        }
    }
```

Also, make sure you have registered your model factory in the ConfigureServices.

```
    public class NopStartup : INopStartup
    {
        public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddScoped<ISupportRequestModelFactory, SupportRequestModelFactory>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation @EasinRobin. I made private constructor, that's why it was not working. I changed it to public and that error is solved!